# How to get relted data from second table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two tables: `users` and `students`. These table are connected by fields:

```
users.id = studetns.user_id
```

I try to get information using request:

```
$students = User::where(function ($query) use ($request) {

            // Filter by name
            if (($term = $request->get("name"))) {
                $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
                $query->where('secondname', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            }

        })->with("details")->where('type', '2')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
        dd($students);
```

You can see `with("details")`, that must to connect tables.

My model `User` is:

```
public function details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Student', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

When I execute query I get error:

```
select * from `users` where `type` = 2 order by `name` desc)
```

It means that was not been connect with second table where there is `name` fiels.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get error: `nknown column 'name' in 'order clause' ` because request works only with one table `users` where there is not field name

Comment: Where is this column then? In students table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `name` and `secondname` are in `students` table, try this:

```
$students = User::where('type', '2')
     ->with(['details' => function ($query) use ($request) {

        if (!empty($request->name)) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%');
            $query->orWhere('secondname', 'like', '%'.$request->name.'%');
        }

        $query->orderBy('name', 'desc');
    }])->get();
```

This will load and order all `students` (or, if `$request->name` variable exists, all `students` filtered by it's value).

PS: As @jedrzej.kurylo said, it makes sense to use `orWhere` operator if you want to find name in `name` column **or** in `secondname`.

Comment: No `type` is in `users` and `name` in `students`

Comment: This will still cause the error, as there is no "name" column in users table.

Comment: Only one remark, this request takes fields from Student table, not from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

The way you load **User** models, by filtering by name in the callback passed to **where()**, causes the error, because there is no **name** column in **users** table, so that simply cannot work.

If you want to load users that have given name in related **students** table, you need to use **whereHas()**:

```
$students = User::whereHas('details', function ($query) use ($request) {            // Filter by name
        if (($term = $request->get("name"))) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
            $query->where('secondname', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
        }
    })
    ->join('details', 'details.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->with("details")
    ->where('type', '2')
    ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I also think you might want to get users whose **name OR secondname** matches the **$term**, so I suggest you replace:

```
  $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
  $query->where('secondname', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
```

with

```
  $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
  $query->orWhere('secondname', 'like', '%' . $term . '%');
```